# Angular momentum dimensions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants

In Cohen-Tannoudji's book vol.1 page 648 the following is said:

$|\psi \rangle$ an arbitrary state.

$\langle\psi|\vec J^2|\psi \rangle=\sum_{i=1}^3\langle\psi|J_i^2|\psi \rangle=\sum_{i=1}^3 ||J_i|\psi\rangle||^2\ge0$

Then it says that the eigenvalues of $\vec J^2$ are of the form $j(j+1)\hbar^2$ and it proceeds with the derivation of the expression of the eigenvalues. I understand everything but the first thing that it's written in the book:

Since $J$ has the dimensions $\hbar$, then $\vec J^2$ has the dimensions $\lambda \hbar^2$.

My question is, where does it come from that $J$ has the dimensions $\hbar$ ?

Edit:

Ultimately this is about $\vec J^2$ and it's eigenvalues, but the reasoning as to why one can write the eignevalues of the form $j(j+1)\hbar^2$ starts with the assumption that the dimensions of $\vec J$ are of the form $\hbar$.
$\vec J$ is supposed to represent an angular momentum, that can be orbital angular momentum, spin angular momentum, total angular momentum.

Comment: Ask yourself: what are the (mksi) units involved in $h$?

Answer (score 0):

The classical angular momentum is

$$\vec L = \vec r \times \vec p$$

which has dimension

$$
\rm [m] \times [kg\ m\ s^{-1}] = [J\,s]
$$

The quantum-mechanical angular momentum operator has the same units by the correspondence principle.